# Selenium cant find elements in specific website

Tags: python, selenium, iframe, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I don't find the element in specific website (https://insurconnect.b3.com.br/menu-web/ctp/TelaPrincipalCetip21)

I tested in other website and it worked.

tried By : Class,Xpath,FullXpath,Css Selector. Can't find the name or Id using the inspector.
I tried to make it wait with time.sleep
I really don't know what to do. My code is here:

```
import pandas as pd
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


nav=webdriver.Edge(executable_path='C:/Users/F00010764/msedgedriver.exe') #o webdrive e o parâmetro mostrando o caminho

#Dados de acesso B3
website_b3 ="https://digital.icatuseguros.com.br/seguro-de-vida?utm_term=icatu%20seguros&utm_campaign=%5BRACC%5D%5BS%5D+Institucional&utm_source=adwords&utm_medium=ppc&hsa_acc=7589317064&hsa_cam=11999175291&hsa_grp=115633742533&hsa_ad=579263938725&hsa_src=g&hsa_tgt=kwd-1564194867&hsa_kw=icatu%20seguros&hsa_mt=b&hsa_net=adwords&hsa_ver=3&gclid=Cj0KCQiA-oqdBhDfARIsAO0TrGEnsUte5EboJEUqACTG82Xp6KFQW9QnNPV5msSmtHjNlq57oOzmFnMaAh9qEALw_wcB" #Link do site b3

nav.get(website_b3)     #entrando no website, nesse em especifico no site da B3
time.sleep(7)
participante_path = nav.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/form/table/tbody/tr/td/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[3]/input")
```

Someone help me?

[image]

Comment: I only change to Edge and it's rigth. Thanks!!

Comment: This probably occurres after the login? I think this is a new question, so please open a new question for that with clear explanations when and how this occurrs. In case this occurres after the login we will need credentials to reproduce your flow

Comment: I stopped again : / 
Now, I have an another problem.

UnexpectedAlertPresentException: unexpected alert open: {Alert text : A sessão anterior foi encerrada.

Último acesso:
 Início: 22/12/2022 - 11:36:24
 Término: 22/12/2022 - 11:40:57
 Estação: WEBCETIP/10.141.8.1/TERM1}
  (Session info: MicrosoftEdge=108.0.1462.54)

A box appeared with this message and a button "ok" that I click and continue.

How can I continue the process using selenium??

Comment: I have no idea when this happens?

Comment: I solve this problema, thanks for all!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The elements you trying to access are inside an iframe, so you need to switch to that iframe in order to access these elements.
The following code works:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")

webdriver_service = Service('C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service, options=options)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
actions = ActionChains(driver)

url = "https://insurconnect.b3.com.br/menu-web/ctp/TelaPrincipalCetip21"
driver.get(url)

wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe#main")))

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "e1"))).send_keys("my_first_input")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "e2"))).send_keys("my_second_input")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "e3"))).send_keys("my_third_input")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "Entrada"))).click()
```

The result before clicking the submit button is:

[image]